# Array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a table in MySQL with two columns.

```
Name  Surname
Mark  A
Mark  B
Mark  C
Jonh  A
John  B
Mark  D
Dean  A
```

If I will make SELECT FROM query and ask only for names column i will have an array looking like this:

```
Mark,Mark,Mark,Jonh,Jonh,Mark,Dean
```

And I want an array looking like this

```
Mark,John,Dean
```

How can I do it with PHP or MySQL?

Comment: You can add `GROUP BY Surname` on the sql end.

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT`

Comment: Alternatively and suboptimally there's also [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DISTINCT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx):

> DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name` FROM tablename
```

Comment: As you were preparing this, I was typing it as a comment lol

Comment: Great minds think alike!

Comment: True.... Funny, I was going to say the same thing in an edit, but you beat me to it lol ;-)

Comment: Pefect solution, thank you :)

Comment: @MateuszC Do tick that little checkmark till she turns Green then ;-)